# Мне требуется переписать небольшой участок кода с C# на C++ для нормальной работы кода однако я не знаю как

Tags: c#, c++, godot

Я не давно только начал изучать c++ да и в общем опыт в программировании не большой но что-то делать уже могу однако то чем я сейчас занимаюсь довольно сложно с моими знаниями, я использую Godot Engine для создания игр и раньше писал в встроенным в движок своим языком как python, он GDScript называется, но захотел перейти на другой язык помощнее пока не знаю зачем, я использую gdnative как называют разработчики "Меж-языковые сценарии (скрипты)" то есть можно использовать разные языки однако подключать это для меня было очень сложно, мне просто требуется переписать старый код с другого языка на c++, решение уже найдено однако я не знаю как "конвертировать" с c# на с++ пусть из-за небольшого различия в синтаксисе, или я чего-то не понимаю и компилятор выдаёт ошибку

```
public class Player : KinematicBody2D
{
 private AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback _stateMachine;
public override void _PhysicsProcess(float delta)
    {
        var animTree = (AnimationTree)GetNode("AnimationTree"); //<=== Именно это
        _stateMachine = (AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback)animTree.Get("parameters/playback"); // <=== И это
        MyFuncton();
    }


    void MyFuncton()
{
     GD.Print(stateMachine.GetCurrentNode());
}
}
```

а так у меня просто скопировано:

```
void Player::_ready()
{
    Variant animTree = (AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback)get_node("AnimationTree");
    _stateMachine = animTree.get("parameters/playback");
}
```

и 3 ошибки:

1я  не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "godot::Node *" в "godot::AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback"

2я  class "godot::Variant" не содержит члена "get"

3я  идентификатор "state_machine" не определен

я подумал что ошибки из-за различий в языках

Comment: Заранее извините за моё не знание если чего-то не понимаю и ещё в headers есть нужные инклюды и объявление _stateMachine а функция ready это препроцесс в godot то есть работает до запуска в движке

Comment: Перепишите для начала вопрос на нормальном русском языке без таких слов как "клепать" и "запарно"

Comment: @CrazyElf это всё фигня. Вот название бы со смыслом сделать ещё.

Comment: @CrazyElf а так нормально? я так хотел выразить своё недовольство потому что мне подключение gdnative съело мои нервы спустя много часов решения казалось бы простых ошибок из-за чего я даже не мог приступить к написанию кода

Comment: @F0remNKB Уже лучше. Хотя вы всё-равно пишете очень много лишний слов, которые к сути вопроса не относятся. Но если не можете сдерживать поток слов, то хотя бы немного его окультуривайте )

Comment: @CrazyElf Критика всегда полезна если она здоровая

Comment: @CrazyElf просто я пишу много лишнего для понимания происходящего даже если это не требуется